# Rails 4 - explicit model name for resource id route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

When defining the following route in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :streams
```

Rails generates the following urls:

```
        streams    GET    /streams(.:format)
                   POST   /streams(.:format)
        new_stream GET    /streams/new(.:format)
       edit_stream GET    /streams/:id/edit(.:format)
            stream GET    /streams/:id(.:format)
                   PATCH  /streams/:id(.:format)
                   PUT    /streams/:id(.:format)
                   DELETE /streams/:id(.:format)
```

I would like to have an explicit resource id, i.e. `:stream_id` instead of `:id`.

**edit:**

For simple resources the solution is like @user2262149 and @vimsha mentioned:

```
resources :streams, :param => :stream_id
```

The problem is with nested resources. If I do this:

```
resources :streams do
  resource :comment, :param => :comment_id
end
```

I will get this route (which is ok):

```
stream_comments   GET  streams/:stream_id/comments(.:format)
```

but on the other hand for the parent resource (again, `:id` instead of `:stream_id`):

```
streams   GET  streams/:id(.:format)
```

So....
If I try to solve it adding `:param => :stream_id` to the parent resource:

```
resources :streams, :param => :stream_id do
  resource :comment, :param => :comment_id
end
```

Then for the parent resource the route is ok:

```
stream GET    /api/streams/:stream_id(.:format)
```

but I get a real mess for the child resource:

```
stream_comments GET    /api/streams/:stream_stream_id/comments(.:format)
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but, in your `routes.rb`,

If you use

```
resources :streams, param: :stream_id
```

Rails will generate the following urls:

```
          streams GET      /streams(.:format)                       streams#index
                  POST     /streams(.:format)                       streams#create
       new_stream GET      /streams/new(.:format)                   streams#new
      edit_stream GET      /streams/:stream_id/edit(.:format)       streams#edit
           stream GET      /streams/:stream_id(.:format)            streams#show
                  PATCH    /streams/:stream_id(.:format)            streams#update
                  PUT      /streams/:stream_id(.:format)            streams#update
                  DELETE   /streams/:stream_id(.:format)            streams#destroy
```

Hope this helps

UPDATE:

I'm not sure if this is best practices or not or if there is a better way but what if you try:

```
resources :streams, param: :stream_id

resources :streams, only: [] do
  resource :comment, param: :comment_id
end
```

Rails would generate the following urls:

```
            streams GET      /streams(.:format)                         streams#index
                    POST     /streams(.:format)                         streams#create
         new_stream GET      /streams/new(.:format)                     streams#new
        edit_stream GET      /streams/:stream_id/edit(.:format)         streams#edit
             stream GET      /streams/:stream_id(.:format)              streams#show
                    PATCH    /streams/:stream_id(.:format)              streams#update
                    PUT      /streams/:stream_id(.:format)              streams#update
                    DELETE   /streams/:stream_id(.:format)              streams#destroy
     stream_comment POST     /streams/:stream_id/comment(.:format)      comments#create
 new_stream_comment GET      /streams/:stream_id/comment/new(.:format)  comments#new
edit_stream_comment GET      /streams/:stream_id/comment/edit(.:format) comments#edit
                    GET      /streams/:stream_id/comment(.:format)      comments#show
                    PATCH    /streams/:stream_id/comment(.:format)      comments#update
                    PUT      /streams/:stream_id/comment(.:format)      comments#update
                    DELETE   /streams/:stream_id/comment(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great, thanks. Just edited my question, since for nested resources it became a little-bit  messy...

Comment: Ok, doesn't look like the most elegant solution, but it works, thanks! What does the `only: []` do?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
resources :streams, :param => :stream_id
```

UPDATE:

What happens when you do this?

```
resources :streams, :param => :stream_id do
  resource :comment, :param => :comment_id
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see the edited part of my question for nested resources.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that in urls of inner object (Comment in this case) the stream_id becomes `:stream_stream_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the post above but without the []:
I used:

```
resources :tickets, param: :ticket_id

resources :tickets do
  resources :entries, param: :entry_id
end
```