# Change the name of parent :parent_id parameter in Routing resources for Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I can change the name of the :id parameter in routing with [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592038/change-the-name-of-the-id-parameter-in-routing-resources-for-rails3) but this can change the nested resource's parameter like if I have

```
resources :companies, param: :company_id do
  resources :shares, only[:index]
end
```

this will generate route like

```
/companies/:company_company_id/shares
```

which is wrong I want route like this

```
/companies/:company_id/shares
```

What I need to do?

Comment: You can find one solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081845/rails-4-explicit-model-name-for-resource-id-route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experienced this before and got the below to fix this... it's ugly though, but I haven't found a better way.

**Change:**

```
resources :companies, param: :company_id do
  resources :shares, only: [:index]
end
```

**To:**
*(notice the blank `only: []`)*

```
resources :companies, param: :company_id
resources :companies, only: [], param: :id do
  resources :shares, only: [:index]
end
```

Now when you run `rake routes` you'll see the correct:

```
/companies/:company_id/shares(.:format)
```

in addition to all the other `companies` endpoints:

```
/companies(.:format)
/companies(.:format)
/companies/new(.:format)
/companies/:company_id/edit(.:format)
/companies/:company_id(.:format)
/companies/:company_id(.:format)
/companies/:company_id(.:format)
/companies/:company_id(.:format)
```

All keeping the same `:company_id` param name.

Answer (score 6):

A more clean way is to use the `member`

```rb
resources :companies, param: :company_id do
  member do
    resources :shares, only[:index]
  end
end
```